# singular values of infinite direct sum of operators

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory, compact-operators, singular-values

Hi and thanks in advance,

Suppose $\bigoplus_{n\in \mathbb N} T_n$ is a bounded operator in $\mathcal{B}(\bigoplus_{n\in \mathbb N} H_n)$, for some infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces $H_n$.

I know that $\bigoplus_{n\in \mathbb N} T_n$ is compact on $\bigoplus_{n\in \mathbb N} H_n$ **iff**

1. for every $n\in \mathbb N$ the operator $T_n$ is compact,
2. $\lim_{n\to \infty}\|T_n\|=0$.

**I wonder if something similar holds for Schatten classes?**

An operator $A$ is in the Schatten class $\mathcal{S}^p(H)$ if the sequence of its singular values $(s_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$, written in decreasing order and counting multiplicity, is in $\ell^{p}(\mathbb N)$.

**Question**: In particular, let $(T_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ be a sequence of operators $T_n\in \mathcal{B}(H_n)$ such that,

- for every $n\in \mathbb N$ the operator $T_n$ has finite rank,
- $(\|T_n\|_{n\in \mathbb N})\in \ell^{p}(\mathbb N)$.

Then

- Is it true that $\bigoplus_{n\in \mathbb N} T_n\in \mathcal{S}^p(\bigoplus_{n\in \mathbb N} H_n)$?
- Should we care about the growth of the ranks of $T_n$ as $n$ goes to infinity?

Comment: Note:
$$
\|T\|_{\mathcal S^p} = \operatorname{tr}(|T|^p)^{1/p} = \left(\sum_{n \in \Bbb N} \operatorname{tr}(|T_n|^p) \right)^{1/p}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement as you currently have it is false.  In particular, taking $T_n = \frac 1{n^2} \operatorname{id}_{H_n}$ with $H_n = \Bbb C^n$ and $p = 1$ yields a counterexample.

Comment: So I need to take into account the ranks of each $T_n$. Hence for $\bigoplus_{n\in \mathbb N} T_n\in \mathcal{S}^p(\bigoplus_{n\in \mathbb N} H_n)$ do we need that $(rank(T_n) \|T_n\|_{n\in \mathbb N})\in \ell^{p}(\mathbb N)$?

Comment: @Curious that would indeed be a sufficient (but not necessary) condition

Comment: Right, so what would it be a necessary condition? Thanks!

Comment: @Curious It is necessary (but not sufficient) to have $(\|T_n\|_n \in \Bbb N) \in \ell^p$.

Comment: @Curious If you want a necessary **and** sufficient condition, you'll have to consider  the Schatten-$p$ norms of each $T_n$.